# Why do I get QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity when trying to use units?

Tags: units

I'm unable to use units in mathematica (10.3.1) When I do

```
Quantity[500, "Feet"] + Quantity[50, "Meters"]
```

the answer I get is

```
QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity[QuantityUnits`Private`UnknownQuantity[50, "Meters"]] + QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity[QuantityUnits`Private`UnknownQuantity[500, "Feet"]]
```

which is not exactly what I was expecting...

Comment: Possible duplicate of… : http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/745753?p_p_auth=zLtRN7qS#opennewwindow

Answer (score 13):

Running

```
RebuildPacletData[]
```

solved the problem, but only on Windows, not on Mac. On my Mac I had to use

```
Get["EntityFramework`"]
EntityValue[]
```

and restart *Mathematica*.

Comment: This works, but the function `RebuildPacletData` does not show up in the documentation search. Where do we find this?

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes see this problem in Mathematica 11.3 and also in 12. I make a CDF tool for our company and users also see this problem in the CDF/Wolfram Player. I don't know why it happens or how to reproduce it, but I have found that when it happens it can be solved with this command:

```
<<QuantityUnitsLoader`
```